# Skipped tests in mocha shown pending in report

Tags: node.js, gulp, mocha.js, gulp-mocha

I am using gulp-mocha to execute my mocha tests with mochawesome-screenshots report

For a particular condition I should skip my test.

[image]

But in report and cli those tests are shown pending not skipped

[image]

[image]

I need to log the test which i skipped to be skipped not pending.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Skipped tests are "Pending" [by definition](https://mochajs.org/#inclusive-tests) in mocha:

> Anything skipped will be marked as pending, and reported as such.